# R programming - how to change values

Tags: r, rename

new to R

I have a variable "location" that have values: "S. SJ" , "S. SJ @ Ashley" ,
"S. SJ @ Ashley Store" .

i need to change any values starting with "S. SJ" to "S. SJ @ Ashley Store"

data:

```
 seq   location
 1     S. SJ
 2     S. SJ @ Ashley Store
 3     S. SJ @ Ashley
```

want:

```
seq  location
1    S. SJ @ Ashley Store
2    S. SJ @ Ashley Store
3    S. SJ @ Ashley Store
```

thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? You'll get better answers if you share the code you've tried & how it did or didn't work as you expect/need. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple such patterns of string that you want to combine to one you can use `case_when` with `grepl`/`str_detect` to match them.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(location = case_when(grepl('S\\.\\s*SJ', location) ~ 'S. SJ @ Ashley Store'))

#  seq             location
#1   1 S. SJ @ Ashley Store
#2   2 S. SJ @ Ashley Store
#3   3 S. SJ @ Ashley Store
```